# Keyword/phrase extraction from free text using NLTK and Python for structured queries

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, information-retrieval

I want to interpret specific keywords from a free text such as "I want to order boiled eggs and spinach soup from nearest restaurants' and use them to search content from my database. 
For e.g i want to extract following specific keyword(s) and want an output similar to following like a tuple of (Keyword type , Keyword value).
e.g ('Food Item','Boiled Eggs') , ('Food Item','Spinach Soup') , ('Location','Nearest Restaurants') etc.

Need to use these values and types to further refine and to query my tables in database.

I was trying hard to find answer using various techniques using python and NLTK but need help to point me to right direction. Am i using the right techniques / frameworks? Need help here

Thanks,
Sammy

Comment: Please go through [this wonderful book](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/ch00.html) that is provided with the NLTK module.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that difficult, but not that super precise either.

Use NLTK's [PoS Tagging](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html), then extract `nouns` and `compound nouns`, and use them in your DB queries.

A natural sentence is practically has two parts, an action, i.e. the verb, and a noun, i.e. the object.

Hence, "I want to order boiled eggs and spinach soup from nearest restaurants" tells us that:

- the action/verb is `order`
- objects/nouns are `boiled eggs` and `spinach soup`
- location is `nearest restaurants`

Comment: Thanks @Jahangir.. As per my understanding , pos tagger will give me a bag of words with speech tagging key words. The problem i am facing is how to relate that 'boiled' and 'eggs' are related into one query word and same with others. Also is there a way to tag them as custom labels like 'Food item' and 'Location; etc.   Or i may have to think about using a completely custom written code to tag labels of my choice to keywords?

Comment: @Sammy [this](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5718/add-custom-labels-to-nltk-information-extractor/5738#5738) is what you are looking for. The simplest way to perform this relation model is to create a lookup table AKA gazetteer.

Comment: @MayurH Thanks for the response. Will look at options like IEPY also.

Comment: Have been trying to use chunking for detecting patterns of tags. But here is one problem i detected with NLTK chunking. Is there a way to detect value within a pos tag and specifically assign custom label in chunking . For example if i want to capture the value 'from' whenever it appears in <IN> tag , is there a way to define a custom label in chunking specifically for this value of <IN> tag?